# What do you do if you ask a question that you regret asking?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

I asked this question: [How to make a "footer" stick to the bottom of a facebox (jQuery plugin) dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12391559/how-to-make-a-footer-stick-to-the-bottom-of-a-facebox-jquery-plugin-dialog)

Some time after I asked it I realize that I should've focused on implementing some other functionality before asking this question (in this case, as mentioned in the question, make the facebox dialog a fixed size, and make a scrollbar appear in it if the content is bigger than the container).

I think it may still be a valid question when I'm done implementing the pre-functionality required to test it, but I know I'll be able to cut the question down and improve it by then.

I think it's also important to mention that the question has few views, no upvotes, a single answer, neither with any upvotes.

Should I:

1. Copy the question content (and save it as template for the yet-to-be-asked improved question) and delete the question?
2. Vote to close the question (since it requires 4 more votes, this seems unreliable), perhaps edit in an "Update" saying I want to close the question and rephrase it in a few days?
3. Leave it as it is, and perhaps just edit it to fit the answer(s) when I know enough about the issue to ask the question in a more useful way?
4. Do something else?

Comment: 1) Bang the keyboard in anger. 2) Cry out to the ceiling, "Why?!?" 3) Curse my parents, my wife, my children, *The Academy* 4) Take up crochet 5) Wake up in a pool of sweat, thankful it was all just a *horrible* dream! ;)

Comment: @AndrewBarber I'm glad you woke up to tell me about it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Leave it as it is

The answer was given to the question as it stands - not to some version of it in the future tailored to the answer.

Both the question and the answer may be of value to a future visitor to the site - seeing it is not being downvoted, you have no real reason to remove it.

When you have done the work to improve the question - ask a new one with your new found knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. This doesn't entirely answer the question for me though. Should I just accept his answer and move on even though I have no clue if his answer is actually a solution to the issue I can't test yet? Should I wait and see if I will be able to test the answer later to see if it's an actual answer?
The problem behind the question is that I didn't share enough code to make the answerers able to test if their answer was an actual solution.

Comment: @AskeB., wait and see. You can't accept it if you don't know if it's the answer. As Oded says, there's no reason to close it, because there is an answer. If your future question turns out to be very different, ask a new one. If at that point the existing answer works, accept it. If it doesn't you could add a comment to the answer, maybe linking to the new question (if appropriate).

Comment: @AskeB. - What's the hurry? And why do you think you _have_ to accept an answer at all? You don't. Accept the answer if it was correct and helped you, once you are certain it has.

Comment: @Oded The hurry is, if it's not the answer I need, the question will most likely never get an actual answer, since it's not a hot question anymore. That in itself may not be a problem (if I no longer need the answer) but it counts towards a bad accept rate which people seem to care about when the look at a question. That's my worry.

Comment: @AskeB. - When it comes to accept rate, there are discussions about getting rid of it altogether.